# Linux Symbolic Linking not working as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, symbolic-link

I have achieved my "goal" several times before but am running into an issue I have not yet experienced before. I have a webserver setup with Nginx on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have my system setup the way I normally would and am attempting to create a symbolic link for the site "virtual host" from the sites-available to the sites-enabled directory. Typically, this is achieve with the following from the primary nginx directory (as root):

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.com
```

While I can move into the enabled directory and view the symbolic link has "worked", when I try and edit the file directly in the sites-enabled directory I see the file is blank and treated as a new file. As a result, my server does not work as expected and pages do not load. When I simply hard copy or hard link the file into the directory:

```
ln /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.com
```

It works without any issue. I however am stuck with two copies of the same file and no symbolic link.

What the heck gives?

Note: here is the structure of my current Nginx directory:

```
root@site.com:/etc/nginx# ls -l
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  4 17:28 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  964 Feb 12 08:41 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2837 Feb 12 08:41 koi-utf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2223 Feb 12 08:41 koi-win
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3463 Feb 12 08:41 mime.types
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1022 Mar  4 21:15 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  596 Feb 12 08:41 scgi_params
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  4 21:15 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  4 21:19 sites-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  623 Feb 12 08:41 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3610 Feb 12 08:41 win-utf
```

Thank you for your help ahead of time!

Edit 1:
Showing the contents of the `sites-enabled` folder with `ls -l`:

```
root@site.com:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Mar  5 10:23 www -> www
```

### Final Answer

So after help from the @Insyte and @Michael Hampton, I figured out how to reproduce my error occassionally. The scenario played out as follows:

```
root@site.com:/etc/nginx# cd sites-available
root@site.com:/etc/nginx/sites-available# ls
www
root@site.com:/etc/nginx/sites-available# ln -s www /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www
root@site.com:/etc/nginx/sites-available# cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
root@site.com:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Mar  5 10:48 www -> www
```

I am not aware of "why" but turns out that if I use full absolute paths each time then the issue does not exist.

Comment: Can you show us the result of `ls -l` on one of these "empty" files?

Comment: @AndrewB - This has been added

Comment: +1 thanks, using absolute paths worked for me as well.

Comment: +1 This worked for me. Can anyone please explain why does this works on providing an absolute path and does not on providing a short path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So what you have there is a symbolic link that links back to itself.  I don't see how that's possible with the command you listed at the top of your question, so I suspect this particular symbolic link was created differently.

I can replicate your scenario like this:

```
sazerac:~ insyte$ cd testlinks/
sazerac:~/testlinks insyte$ ls
sazerac:~/testlinks insyte$ ln -s www www
sazerac:~/testlinks insyte$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 insyte  staff  3 Mar  5 10:33 www -> www
```

Let's try an experiment.  Execute the following commands exactly as listed:

```
echo "hello insyte" > /etc/nginx/sites-available/insyte
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/insyte /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled|grep insyte
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/insyte
```

Comment: so I think I figured out what is going on and really appreciate your help. I'll post my final findings in the OP above.

Answer (score 6):

You've somehow managed to create a symbolic link that links to itself. I didn't even know you could do that, but I'm quite sure it won't have the result you want.

To fix it, remove the symlink and recreate it correctly.

```
rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www
```

Or just use the `-f` option to `ln` and it may remove the invalid symlink for you.

```
ln -fs /etc/nginx/sites-available/www /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I attempted this before exactly and got:

root@site.com:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ln -fs /etc/nginx/sites-available/www /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www
ln: accessing `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www': Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: You'll probably have to delete it yourself, then.

Comment: see final answer in my OP. I was not aware a full path had to be used each time (and fairly certain I did given the OP had a full path stated but I was able to reproduce my error above.

Comment: The symlink is created exactly as you specify, whether it's a relative or absolute path. If relative, it will be relative to the directory the symlink is created in, _not_ the directory you were in when you created it.

Comment: this helped me instantly

Answer (score 0):

Out of habit:

- I always use `ln -sfn` to ensure any old links are updated without trouble.
- I always use an absolute path:

```sh
ln -sfn /absolute/path/to/original /absolute/path/to/link
```

That keeps me out of much trouble.